# Win32::SerialPort constructor goes buffer-overflow when reference variable is given

Tags: perl, variables, serial-port, tk-toolkit, buffer-overflow

This works well:

```
my $PortObj;    
$PortObj = new Win32::SerialPort ("COM12") || die "Can't open COM\n";
```

However when I try to provide a variable instead of "COM12" from TK Entry, like this:

```
my $portNumVar = "12";
my $portNum = $mw->Entry(-justify=>'center',-width=>'5',-textvariable=>\$portNumVar)->pack();
```

Inside a subroutine (after a button click):

```
my $PortObj;
my $com = "COM".$portNumVar;
print $com;
$PortObj = new Win32::SerialPort ($com) || die "Can't open COM\n";
```

I get this error:

> Win32::API::Call: parameter 1 had a buffer overflow at
>   C:/Perlx86_5.16/site/lib/Win32API/CommPort.pm line 176.

How is it even possible? Shouldn't it be the same?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Interesting. How about you `use Carp::Always` and get a stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem with Wx and Win32::SerialPort.
In my case this workaround worked:
    `$PortObj = new Win32::SerialPort (eval(qq("$com"))) || die "Can't open COM\n";`

Comment: @JAL The first few words of this post make it seem like not an answer, but the second sentence contains a proposed solution to the problem, so this seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: This worked for me, but can anyone explain why it worked?

Answer (score -1):

You need to dereference a variable if it is a reference (passed as \$val) to get the right value and not its memory address (pointer).

```
my $com = "COM".$$portNumVar;
```

Comment: No. Using `$portNumVar` is OK here. The reference is just for the `-textvariable` option.